# How do I post data with custom json structure using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am using Wordpress with Woocommerce platform. I must send selected order details to an API(3rd party accounting system) after an order has been successfully made.

Current jquery ajax code

```
  j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://mywebsite/api/orderupload',
    cache: false,
    data: {

    },
    beforeSend:function() {

    },
    success: function (result) {
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
    complete:function(){
    }
  });
```

The structure of the json data that must be inside **data {}** to the post request above is:

```
{
  "order": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "public",
      "vat": "false",
      "org_nr": "123456-789",
      "name": "Carl Lorem",
      "phone": "639055543227",
      "address": {
        "name": "Carl Lorem",
        "address": "Riften Street",
        "zipcode": "2323",
        "city": "Dawnstar City",
        "country": "US"
      },
      "email": "carllorem@gmail.com"
    },
    "transaction": {
      "storage": {
        "name": "Los Angeles",
        "location": "Road Earth",
      },
      "insurance": {
        "name": "Igsum Nat",
        "cost": "30"
      },
      "date": {
        "start": "2018-4-23",
        "end": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know how can I structure my json data for my post request? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you don't need to "structure your data". It is an object and you can put the whole thing into `data: myObject`. JSON is just a string-representation of an object (JavaScriptObjectNotation)

Comment: oh, there's a `,` too much after `"Road Street",`

Comment: @Jeff that is just a typo. I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    "order": {
        "customer": {
            "type": "public",
            "vat": "false",
            "org_nr": "123456-789",
            "name": "Carl Lorem",
            "phone": "639055543227",
            "address": {
                "name": "Carl Lorem",
                "address": "Riften Street",
                "zipcode": "2323",
                "city": "Dawnstar City",
                "country": "US"
            },
            "email": "carllorem@gmail.com"
        },
        "transaction": {
            "storage": {
                "name": "Los Angeles",
                "location": "Los Angeles, Road Street"
            },
            "insurance": {
                "name": "Igsum Nat",
                "cost": "30"
            },
            "date": {
                "start": "2018-4-23",
                "end": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The json you attached was invalid i send you a correct one,

About the ajax part:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/mywebsite/api/orderupload',
       data: ("myjson": myjson},
       dataType: 'json'
 success: function (response) {
console.log(response)
}
   error: function(xhr,status,error) {
      console.log(error)
    },
})
```

The myjson variable is your json that you want to send through ajax. After that your back-end takes over on how you handle it.

Comment: Glad i could help you